# How to change a HTML element's text to another element in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

As the title says, I'd like to change a DOM element's textContent to a span, using PHP. Like from this:

```
<div class="dummy">Here is my content.</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="dummy"><span class="newSpan"></span></div>
```

I've tried to set the content to empty like

```
$sourceDOMElement->nodeValue = ""; //OR
$sourceDOMElement->textContent = "";
```

But none worked for some reason. After this, I'd like to append a new child to the element with the new span I'd like to insert.

How could I make this work?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: [Here's my whole code, where I have to do this.](https://pastebin.com/VzRriSQ3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the nodeValue property if you want to set text content of an element like this

```
$el = $dom->getElementById('foo');
$el->nodeValue = 'hello world';
```

this automatically escapes < and >, so you can't insert HTML like this.

so to do that u can go with :

```
DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment:

$frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML('<h1>foo</h1>');
$el->appendChild($frag);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen exactly this answer in another question, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```php
$content = '<div class="dummy">aaaaaaa</div>';
$DOM_inner_HTML = new DOMDocument();
$DOM_inner_HTML->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ) );
$content_node = $DOM_inner_HTML->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$content_node->textContent  = '<span class="newSpan"></span>';
```

Comment: i try this and it is works . if you didnt see the tag is because of tags are rendering in browser

Comment: I basically do the same but I use $dom->loadHTMLFile($html); because I have to load a file, but it doesn't work. Could it be a problem?

Comment: try with file_get_content and test it again!

Comment: Added my whole function to my question. Could you please take a look at it?